# Swift compiler error: missing argument labels

Tags: ios, swift, xcode

I run `Swift` on `Xcode 8.3.3`. Here I get an error regarding closures.

It seems that this part is all correct `[var intro = introToFriends("Jim", "Pam")
intro]` yet isn't clicking.

What's the issue?

[image]

Comment: Post your code as text to be able to copy, not as an image.

Comment: Use introToFriends(friendOne: "Jim", friendTwo: "Pam"), argument names

Comment: There are 60 search results for  `[swift] missing argument labels` ...

Answer (score 5):

Later Swift versions require explicit argument labels when calling a function. In your case it needs to read:

```
var intro = introToFriends(friendOne: "Jim", friendTwo: "Pam")
```

Alternatively, you can allow for omitting the use of argument labels if you add underscores to the parameter labels in the function declaration such as:

```
func introToFriends(_ friendOne: String, _ friendTwoString) {
    ...
}
```

For more details [check the official Apple documentation on function argument labels](https://developer.apple.com/library/content/documentation/Swift/Conceptual/Swift_Programming_Language/Functions.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP40014097-CH10-ID166).